# PHP Date() error after upgrading to 5.3.8

Tags: php

I'm getting the following error all over my websites after upgrading to PHP 5.3.8:

> Warning: strtotime() [function.strtotime]: It is not safe to rely on
>   the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the
>   date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In
>   case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this
>   warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We
>   selected 'America/Chicago' for 'CDT/-5.0/DST' instead in ....

My php.ini file has date.timezone = "America/Chicago" so I'm not sure why this warning is being thrown.

### Note

Defining on a per page basis is not feasible at this point. This is impacting several websites and thousands of pages. I have checked phpinfo() for the site and see the following response:

http://screencast.com/t/EPOCW9VdR

Comment: double check that the php.ini that has the timezone setting is the one php is loading. you can check phpinfo() for which one is being used. Also, maybe restart apache.

Comment: Have you restarted apache since the upgrade / change to php.ini?

Comment: @jasonbar - yes I have. Also, just checked and phpinfo() even presents the error. I will paste in an edit above.

Comment: although, defining on a per page basis is not feasible as you stated, although not idea, if using apache, you can set the value in a .htaccess or the httpd.conf file. `php_value date.timezone America/Chicago` even if just a temp fix.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn - good suggestion, I will make the change in .htaccess file but still confused by the overall error. I posted a link image above.

Comment: what does `Configuration File (php.ini) Path` and `Loaded Configuration File ` say in the phpinfo page? make sure it points to the same file you are checking. it is very possible that an old php.ini file is lingering that is overriding the value.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn - well, I checked my apache error logs more thoroughly and found the issue was actually a conflict earlier in the file which caused execution to stop. I corrected and don't seem to be facing the same error. If you want to provide your .htaccess suggestion as an answer below, I will accept as an answer as I feel it gives a good temporary solution to anybody in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

double check that the php.ini that has the timezone setting is the one php is loading. you can check phpinfo() for which one is being used. Also, maybe restart apache.

although, defining on a per page basis is not feasible as you stated, although not idea, if using apache, you can set the value in a .htaccess or the httpd.conf file. php_value date.timezone America/Chicago even if just a temp fix.

So you can accept and close the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the timezone within your php file using

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

Comment: thanks but this is not feasible as I am talking about 30 websites with thousands of pages. I'll add a note above.

Comment: you dont have to define it in every page but u can define it in the config file of your website

Comment: that assumes we have one (many sites which do not). Unless you are implying the apache htaccess file.